# How to always display a control on the currently active tab of a TabControl?

Tags: vb.net

I have a tab control with two tabs. Both tabs have controls which are unique to them, but there is one control which I would like to always appear on whichever tab is currently active.

I figure I just need to add some code to `TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged()`.

I tried

```
MyControl.Parent = TabControl1.TabPages(
                           TabControl1.TabPages.IndexOf(TabControl1.SelectedTab))
      MyControl.Parent.Update()   ' is this necessary?
```

and I also tried

```
TabControl1.TabPages(
 TabControl1.TabPages.IndexOf(TabControl1.SelectedTab)).Controls.Add(SeMyControl)
```

but neither worked (the control moved once, but when I went back to the original tab, the control did not appear there.

googling found someone suggesting

```
TabControl1.TabPages(TabControl1.TabIndex).Controls.Add(MyControl)
```

but that looks dodgy as the control is never removed from the old tab, so repeated switching would probably add the control multiple times.

I feel that I am close, but not quite ... how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that works fine since Controls.Add() changes the Parent property.  Which automatically removes it from the tab page it was on before.  A control instance can only have one parent.

The more straight-forward approach is to simply *not* put the control on a tab page but leave it parented to the form which a lower Z-order so it is always on top of the tab control.  The only problem with that is that the designer will hassle you.  It automatically sucks the control into the tab page when you move it on top of the tab control.  One trick to fix that is to leave it off the tab control and change its Location property in the form constructor.

Comment: +1 Sounds good, thanks. I guess that I can either, as you say eave it off the tab control and change its Location property in the form constructor, or don't have it in the designer at all and construct it dynamically in the form constructor.

Comment: That's okay too, don't forget SetChildIndex() to move it in front.

Answer (score 1):

Using your second code snippet that you are concerned about because it doesn't remove it from the original tab, why not just remove it from the original tab before you add it to the new tab?

Maybe something like: TabControl1.TabPages(TabControl1.TabIndex).Controls.Remove(MyControl)

Comment: +1 Ok, I'll give it a try & get back to you. The tricky part is to know which tab was the old one, but I can probably bypass that by   

    MyControl.Parent.Controls.Remove(MyControl)

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying. I guess you could iterate through the tabs and check: TabPage.Contains(MyControl). If it does, then remove it and add it to your newly activated page.